# setup br100 and nova network fixed ip range

Tags: bridge, openstack

This is my situation:

- An ESXi 5.0 Server (I'm doing a project for my BD);
- A pool with 2 VM (1 controller node and 1 compute node)
- Ubuntu 13.04 amd64 Server installed on both VM
- The controller IP is 172.25.27.11
- i've successfully setup keystone, glance and partially nova

My problem with nova is the creation of the br100 and the fixed range subnet.
Inside the `/etc/network/interfaces` file i have:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto br100
iface br100 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0
```

inside the file `/etc/nova/nova.conf` i have:

```
# NETWORK
network_manger_nova=nova.network.manger.FlatDHCPManager
my_ip=172.25.27.11
fixed_range=172.25.27.0/24
public_interface=eth0
vlan_interface=eth0
flat_interface=eth0
flat_network_bridge=br100
```

I have also enabled ip forwarding inside `/etc/sysctl.conf` and i have set eth0 promisc with `ip link set eth0 promisc on`.

The cmd `brctl show` show:

```
bridge name      bridge id    STP enabled        interfaces
br100            8000.xxxx    no                 eth0
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Ever get to the bottom of your problem?

Comment: yes! i'm using quantum with ovs now xD